# In-app purchases without google wallet merchant account

Tags: in-app-purchase, android-pay

I'm from a "not supported country" to create google wallet merchant accounts, that means I can only create free apps.

So my question is, Is there a way to have in-app purchases in my app without this account? I mean are there any third party companies that can handle the transaction?

Well thanks a lot for you time to check this question.